# Capture and transmit NTSC with ESP32? (w/video decoder chip)

Tags: esp32, ntsc

Is it possible to use a video decoder (ie. MAX9526) with an ESP32 to capture an NTSC composite video signal and then transmit over a web service?

Can anybody give me any advice or information?

Comment: The esp32 i2s peripheral might be able to keep up, but the data will need to be compressed or decimated to send via wifi. Besides, the chip is NRND

Comment: @Kartman Unfortunately the chip does not connect to I2S bus, so that's not an option.

Comment: The i2s peripheral on the esp32 will do 16 bit clocked parallel data at fairly high speed and with dma support. It can easily generate vga. Not sure if it would do 54MHz though. 27MHz maybe.

Comment: Esp32 technical reference: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf#page315

Comment: This is like towing a 30 foot boat with a bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, because for starters, the ESP32 has no peripheral which would support inrerfacing with the parallel video bus.